# Is Array.ConstrainedCopy() anything more than a backup-and-copy operation?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I've been looking at `Array.ConstrainedCopy`, and I'm having trouble figuring out why its implementation is so behind the scenes, in the CLR internals.

#### Does `ConstrainedCopy` do anything more than the following?

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, CER.Success)]
static void ConstrainedCopy(Array src, int iSrc, Array dest, int iDest, int len)
{
    Array backup = Array.CreateInstance(dest.GetType().GetElementType(), len);
    Array.Copy(dest, iDest, backup, 0, len);
    try { Array.Copy(src, iSrc, dest, iDest, len); }
    catch { Array.Copy(backup, 0, dest, iDest, len); throw; }
}
```

If so, what else does it do?
If not, then why is the implementation treated so specially by the CLR, and not in pure C#/.NET code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `Array.ConstrainedCopy` is different from your sample implementation. `Array.ConstrainedCopy` checks beforehand whether there is *any* chance the copy might throw an exception, and if so, refuses to copy at all. For example, copying from an `int[]` to an `object[]` involves boxing the `int`s, which might throw an `OutOfMemoryException`, so `Array.ConstrainedCopy` doesn't even attempt to copy.

```
object[] dst = { 1, 2 };
int[] src = { 3, 4 };
Array.ConstrainedCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, 2);
```

> **ArrayTypeMismatchException occurred**
>
> Array.ConstrainedCopy will only work on array types that are provably compatible, without any form of boxing, unboxing, widening, or casting of each array element.  Change the array types (i.e., copy a Derived[] to a Base[]), or use a mitigation strategy in the CER for Array.Copy's less powerful reliability contract, such as cloning the array or throwing away the potentially corrupt destination array.